# Weird result with Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, multivariable-calculus

Take zero mean MVN on k dimensions: 
$$ p(x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt {( 2 \pi ) ^k |\Sigma|}}e^{-\frac {1} {2}  x \Sigma^{-1} x}$$
we will surely agree that $p(x)\leq1$ for all $x$, including $x=0$ ($x\in\mathbb R^k$). Set $x=0$. So:
$$ p(x) = \frac 1 {\sqrt {( 2 \pi ) ^k |\Sigma|}}e^{-\frac {1} {2}  0 \Sigma^{-1} 0}=$$
$$ \frac 1 {\sqrt {( 2 \pi ) ^k |\Sigma|}}\leq1\implies( 2 \pi ) ^k |\Sigma|\geq1\implies  |\Sigma|\geq(2 \pi ) ^{-k}$$

But $\Sigma$ can be any positive definite matrix, its eigenvalues can be positive yet much smaller than $(2 \pi ) ^{-k}$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The density need not be $\leqslant 1$. And if the variance is small enough, it is greater than $1$ around $0$.

Comment: Very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(x)\le 1$ is wrong.

The equivalent is $\forall A\subset \Bbb R^d$,
$$
\int_A p(x) dx \le 1
$$but you can't say anything is $|A|$ is small.